# Individual stripe account

Tags: cognito-forms

do I need a stripe account in order to get payment via stripe when I use your forms? Or you are collecting the all payments into our account on cognito?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).  You will need your own individual Stripe account to link to your forms. The payments will be processed via our integration with Stripe and deposited in to your Stripe account.

Stripe handles processing, depositing, and transferring all transactions. Cognito Forms leverages the Stripe API to integrate payment collection and refund functionality into your forms.